# Importing IBIS in Python

Tags: python, import, module, ibis

I am trying to use [ibis](https://ibis-project.org/docs/3.0.2/) in my code and while importing it gives an error mentioned below stating that an attribute is called that doesn't exist and when I checked I found the same thing. It also doesn't have a window attribute inside the rules module. I tried updating ibis and did setup the whole project again. I am new to coding in python so sorry if I could not explain my question correctly.

Error-

```
expr = Arg(rlz.analytic)
AttributeError: module 'ibis.expr.rules' has no attribute 'analytic'
```

Code(This is inside the IBIS code in conda environment)-

```
from .. import rules as rlz


@public
class WindowOp(ValueOp):
    expr = Arg(rlz.analytic)
    window = Arg(rlz.window(from_base_table_of="expr"))
    output_type = rlz.array_like('expr')
```

Answer (score 2):

There are (frustratingly) two different `ibis` projects.  You have probably installed the web templating framework called `ibis`.

If you do `pip uninstall ibis` and then `pip install ibis-framework` (or `conda install ibis-framework`) your code example should work.

Comment: This helped a lot! For me, in addition to uninstalling `ibis`, I also had to uninstall and reinstall `ibis-framework`. After that, I could successfully run `import ibis.selectors as s`.